Magit: getting error "transient-setup: Symbol’s function definition is void: transient-prefix-object" after pressing "b" in magit buffer
I am new to Lisp and beginner in Emacs. I am running Magit from git repository. Since my organization doesn't allow downloading packages from Melpa/Elpa, I had to clone all dependencies manually under d:/emacs_packages.
When I press b to issue a branch related command, I get the below error,
transient-setup: Symbol’s function definition is void: transient-prefix-object
I tried following the debugging instructions here: https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Debugging-Tools.html
Output of M-x magit-version,
Magit v3.3.0-1048-gb9948f95, Transient 0.4.3, Git 2.39.2, Emacs 29.3, windows-nt

Output of M-x magit-emacs-Q-command
"d:/Programs/emacs-29.3/bin/emacs" "-Q" "--eval" "(setq debug-on-error t)" "-L" "d:/emacs_packages/compat/" "-L" "d:/emacs_packages/dash.el/" "-L" "d:/Programs/emacs-29.3/share/emacs/29.3/lisp/" "-L" "d:/emacs_packages/with-editor/lisp/" "-L" "d:/emacs_packages/magit/lisp/" "-l" "d:/emacs_packages/magit/lisp/magit"

After I started emacs using the above command, pressing b in magit buffer gave me the below trace,
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function transient-prefix-object)
  transient--exit-and-debug(error (void-function transient-prefix-object))
  (transient-prefix-object)
  (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope)
  (and magit-branch-direct-configure (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope))
  (closure (t) nil (and magit-branch-direct-configure (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope)))()
  transient--do-suffix-p((closure (t) nil (and magit-branch-direct-configure (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope))) nil nil nil nil nil nil nil t)
  transient--use-suffix-p(#<transient-column transient-column-82094948e0>)
  transient--init-group(nil [1 transient-column (:if (closure (t) nil (and magit-branch-direct-configure (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope))) :description (closure (t) nil (concat (propertize "Configure " 'face 'transient-heading) (propertize (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope) 'face 'magit-branch-local)))) ((1 transient-suffix (:key "d" :command magit-branch.<branch>.description)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "u" :command magit-branch.<branch>.merge/remote)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "r" :command magit-branch.<branch>.rebase)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "p" :command magit-branch.<branch>.pushRemote)))])
  transient--init-child(nil [1 transient-column (:if (closure (t) nil (and magit-branch-direct-configure (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope))) :description (closure (t) nil (concat (propertize "Configure " 'face 'transient-heading) (propertize (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope) 'face 'magit-branch-local)))) ((1 transient-suffix (:key "d" :command magit-branch.<branch>.description)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "u" :command magit-branch.<branch>.merge/remote)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "r" :command magit-branch.<branch>.rebase)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "p" :command magit-branch.<branch>.pushRemote)))])
  #f(compiled-function (c) #<bytecode -0x141a09460b7d4bc2>)([1 transient-column (:if (closure (t) nil (and magit-branch-direct-configure (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope))) :description (closure (t) nil (concat (propertize "Configure " 'face 'transient-heading) (propertize (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope) 'face 'magit-branch-local)))) ((1 transient-suffix (:key "d" :command magit-branch.<branch>.description)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "u" :command magit-branch.<branch>.merge/remote)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "r" :command magit-branch.<branch>.rebase)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "p" :command magit-branch.<branch>.pushRemote)))])
  cl-mapcan(#f(compiled-function (c) #<bytecode -0x141a09460b7d4bc2>) ([1 transient-column (:if (closure (t) nil (and magit-branch-direct-configure (eieio-oref (transient-prefix-object) 'scope))) :description (closure (t) nil (concat (propertize "Configure " 'face 'transient-heading) (propertize (eieio-oref ... ...) 'face 'magit-branch-local)))) ((1 transient-suffix (:key "d" :command magit-branch.<branch>.description)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "u" :command magit-branch.<branch>.merge/remote)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "r" :command magit-branch.<branch>.rebase)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "p" :command magit-branch.<branch>.pushRemote)))] [1 transient-column (:if-non-nil magit-branch-direct-configure :description "Configure repository defaults") ((1 transient-suffix (:key "R" :command magit-pull.rebase)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "P" :command magit-remote.pushDefault)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "B" :description "Update default branch" :command magit-update-default-branch :inapt-if-not magit-get-some-remote)))] [1 transient-column (:description "Arguments") ((7 transient-switch (:key "-r" :description "Recurse submodules when checking out an existing b..." :argument "--recurse-submodules" :command transient:magit-branch:--recurse-submodules :if (closure (t) nil (magit-git-version>= "2.13")))))] [1 transient-columns nil ([1 transient-column (:description "Checkout") ((1 transient-suffix (:key "b" :description "branch/revision" :command magit-checkout)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "l" :description "local branch" :command magit-branch-checkout)) (6 transient-suffix (:key "o" :description "new orphan" :command magit-branch-orphan)))] [1 transient-column (:description "") ((1 transient-suffix (:key "c" :description "new branch" :command magit-branch-and-checkout)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "s" :description "new spin-off" :command magit-branch-spinoff)) (5 transient-suffix (:key "w" :description "new worktree" :command magit-worktree-checkout)))] [1 transient-column (:description "Create") ((1 transient-suffix (:key "n" :description "new branch" :command magit-branch-create)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "S" :description "new spin-out" :command magit-branch-spinout)) (5 transient-suffix (:key "W" :description "new worktree" :command magit-worktree-branch)))] [1 transient-column (:description "Do") ((1 transient-suffix (:key "C" :description "configure..." :command magit-branch-configure)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "m" :description "rename" :command magit-branch-rename)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "x" :description "reset" :command magit-branch-reset)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "k" :description "delete" :command magit-branch-delete)))] [1 transient-column (:description "") ((7 transient-suffix (:key "h" :description "shelve" :command magit-branch-shelve)) (7 transient-suffix (:key "H" :description "unshelve" :command magit-branch-unshelve)))])] [1 transient-columns (:hide #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x13503b11332c7edf>)) ([1 transient-column (:description "Value commands") ((1 transient-suffix (:key "C-x s  " :description "Set" :command transient-set)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "C-x C-s" :description "Save" :command transient-save)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "C-x C-k" :description "Reset" :command transient-reset)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "C-x p  " :description "Previous value" :command transient-history-prev)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "C-x n  " :description "Next value" :command transient-history-next)))] [1 transient-column (:description "Sticky commands") ((1 transient-suffix (:key "C-g" :description "Quit prefix or transient" :command transient-quit-one)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "C-q" :description "Quit transient stack" :command transient-quit-all)) (1 transient-suffix (:key "C-z" :description "Suspend transient stack" :command transient-suspend)))] [1 transient-column (:description "Customize") ((1 transient-suffix (:key "C-x t" :command transient-toggle-common :description #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1feb4ba6d746cc65>))) (1 transient-suffix (:key "C-x l" :description "Show/hide suffixes" :command transient-set-level)))])]))
  transient--init-suffixes(magit-branch)
  transient--init-objects(magit-branch nil (:scope "add-imenu"))
  transient-setup(magit-branch nil nil :scope "add-imenu")
  magit-branch("add-imenu")
  funcall-interactively(magit-branch "add-imenu")
  command-execute(magit-branch)

My emacs configuration file contains the following (relevant) code,
;; dash.el -- needed by winnum-mode
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/dash.el")

;; emacs-winnum
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/emacs-winum")
(require 'winum)
(winum-mode)

;; compat (https://github.com/emacs-compat/compat) -- needed by Magit
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/compat")
(require 'compat)

;; with-editor (https://github.com/magit/with-editor) -- needed by Magit
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/with-editor/lisp")

;; magit (https://magit.vc/)
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/magit/lisp")
(require 'magit)

NOTE: Rest of the operations like push/pull are working fine (I am able to clone repositories using M-x magit-clone-regular without any issues).
UPDATE 2024-07-16: As per comments from @Drew and @NickD tried the following,

Didn't find transient-prefix-object function (I have ivy/swiper loaded, which didn't show presence of the above function after C-h f)
C-h f transient-setup showed the help of the function
M-: (featurep 'transient) shows t in the mini-buffer


Likely a duplicate question... is the library that defines transient-prefix-object loaded before you try to use that function? If not...

What does C-h f transient-prefix-object say? What about C-h f transient-setup? Both of these functions are defined in transient.el, so if the second one is known, the first one should be known as well. What does M-: (featurep 'transient) say?

Thanks to the comments from @Drew and @NickD, I referred the comment within magit.el and found few required packages missing.
Cloning the transient, seq.el packages and including them in the load-path solved my issue.
The updated init.el looks like,
;; dash.el -- needed by winnum-mode
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/dash.el")

;; emacs-winnum
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/emacs-winum")
(require 'winum)
(winum-mode)

;; compat (https://github.com/emacs-compat/compat) -- needed by Magit
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/compat")
(require 'compat)

;; with-editor (https://github.com/magit/with-editor) -- needed by Magit
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/with-editor/lisp")

;; seq.el -- needed by magit
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/seq.el")

;; transient -- needed by magit
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/transient/lisp")

;; magit (https://magit.vc/)
(add-to-list 'load-path "D:/emacs_packages/magit/lisp")
(require 'magit)

UPDATE: As per documentation of seq.el (https://github.com/NicolasPetton/seq.el) the package is part of Emacs from Emacs 25.1. So, there is no need to clone and include the seq.el package for Magit.
